# Retrieve Data from SQL Server based on TextBox value in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database with 4 columns `HouseNo`, `Date`, `Time` and `IndoorTemp`. In my C# Windows application I have 4 textboxes, one each for the above columns.

The user enters the HouseNo, Date and Time values in the Text Box. The inputs here should be a part of my SQL Where Clause with the output as the Indoor Temperature. This should then be displayed in the last text box.

I have used this connection:

```
    // Create a String to hold the database connection string.
    string sdwConnectionString = @"Data Source=IE1ADTBD5ZL1S\;Initial Catalog=ThermostatData2;Integrated Security=True";

    // Create a connection
    SqlConnection sdwDBConnection = new SqlConnection(sdwConnectionString);
```

I tried a code to do this but it failed. 
My code is,

```
cmd.IndoorTemp = "select * from ThermData where HouseNo = '" + HouseNovalue.Text + "' and Date = '" + Datevalue.Text + "' and Time = '" + Timevalue.Text + "' ";
```

How do i achieve the desired result.

I am new to C# and do not know much. All the above code was also with the help of a few blogs.

Do please help me out on this one. Also suggest a good book where i could learn to program C# with SQL Server. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do not build the query by string concatenation! Use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    c.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IndoorTemp FROM ThermData WHERE HouseNo = @HouseNo AND Date = @Date AND Time = @Time")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseNo", HouseNovalue.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Datevalue.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Timevalue.Text);

        var indoorTemp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Indoortemp.Text = indoorTemp;
    }
}
```

In this example you're building a new `SqlConnection`, but you're leveraging the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement to ensure it's properly disposed. You are doing the same thing for the `SqlCommand`. Then, you are leveraging parameterized statements to ensure you're safe from SQL Injection.

> And don't shy away from this approach even if it's just a personal project that nobody else uses because you practice how you play. If you don't use parameterized SQL when you practice you certainly won't when you play.

Finally, you're leveraging [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) which returns the first column from the first row of the result set -and that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use parametrized query:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ThermData where HouseNo = @houseno and Date = @date and Time = @time", sdwDBConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@houseno", HouseNovalue.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Datevalue.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", Timevalue.Text);
```

to get results you can do:

```
sdwDBConnection.Open();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read()) //if there is at least one result
{
    //data from reader
    IndoorTemp.Text = reader["IndoorTemp"];  //access value returned for column IndoorTemp
}
```